# Using not exists for a condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to a query select from table days the dates that not found in table ch_inout I have this table "days":

```
  date_1
  2019-08-01
  2019-08-02
  2019-08-03
  2019-08-04
  2019-08-05
  2019-08-06
  2019-08-07
  2019-08-08
  2019-08-09
  2019-08-10
```

And second table: ch_inout"

```
id_emp    date_1   
2        2019-08-01  
2        2019-08-03  
2        2019-08-04  
2        2019-08-05  
2        2019-08-06  
2        2019-08-07  
2        2019-08-08      
6        2019-08-01  
6        2019-08-03   
6        2019-08-05  
6        2019-08-06  
6        2019-08-07  
6        2019-08-08
```

I tried this code:

```
SELECT    Date_1   from  [dbo].[days] not EXISTS   SELECT  id_emp,Date_1  FROM ch_inout
```

The result expected:

```
id_emp   date_1   
2        2019-08-02  
2        2019-08-09  
2        2019-08-10          
6        2019-08-02  
6        2019-08-04      
6        2019-08-09  
6        2019-08-10
```

Comment: And what was wrong with your code?

Comment: The result expected :not what i want how could i do that to same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `CROSS JOIN` to produce all combinations, and then discard the existing ones using a `LEFT JOIN`, as in:

```
select e.id_emp, d.date_1
from days d
cross join (select distinct id_emp from ch_inout) e
left join ch_inout c on c.id_emp = e.id_emp and c.date_1 = d.date_1
where c.id_emp is null
order by e.id_emp, d.date_1
```

Result:

```
id_emp  date_1
------  ----------
2       2019-08-02
2       2019-08-09
2       2019-08-10
6       2019-08-02
6       2019-08-04
6       2019-08-09
6       2019-08-10
```

See [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/7039b/1).

Comment: but the result it just not the same in above "result expected" as i mention it sir

Comment: Could you found any solution sir please ?

Comment: @programmer_25 Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You want `not exists` *with a correlation clause*:

```
SELECT d.Date_1 
FROM [dbo].[days] d
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ch_inout io WHERE io.Date_1 = d.Date_1);
--------------------------------------------------^ correlation clause
```

EDIT:

You seem to want all days not with the given `id_emp`:

```
SELECT d.Date_1 
FROM [dbo].[days] d CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT DISTINCT id_emp FROM ch_inout
     ) e
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM ch_inout io
                  WHERE io.Date_1 = d.Date_1 AND io.id_emp = e.id_emp
                 );
```

Comment: but the result it just not the same in above "result expected" as i mention it sir

Comment: the result too not right , i want the id_emp and date_1 columns the last query you edit it does not match for the the result right sir , hope i found a solution

Comment: Hope you could find the solution sir , please to save my days

Answer (score 0):

You can use [EXCEPT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) here.

```
SELECT Date_1 from [dbo].[days] 
EXCEPT 
SELECT Date_1 FROM ch_inout
```

Comment: but the result it just not the same in above "result expected" as i mention it sir

Comment: Could you found any solution ?

Comment: We are all guessing as to what you want because it isn't very clear from your post.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
cte1(id_emp, date_1) as
(
select distinct(t1.id_emp), t2.date_1
from ch_inout t1
cross join days t2
)
select * from cte1
except
select * from ch_inout
```